# UIBarButtonItem ignoring just about every action, ever

Tags: iphone, objective-c, user-interface, uibarbuttonitem

I have a toolbar, in which is placed a UIBarButtonItem. The selector is targeted at a custom view of mine; a method with this signature:

```
-(IBAction)pop{code}
```

However, clicking it does not cause any action to occur. The buttonitem doesn't appear to respond to the click either, it just stays gray.

Linking a UIButton's TouchUpInside event to the pop method is fine, it operates the method and displays the popover. But as soon as I connect the BarButtonItem's selector to it instead, it stops responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the selector has no colon after it - `@selector(pop)`.  If you use `@selector(pop:)` it expects a `(void)pop:(id)sender { ... }` function.

Comment: I've tried it both ways. I'm actually hooking it up via IB, so it automatically changes to add the colon either way. Either way, I get zilch! :(

Comment: Try "Build/Clean", usually fixes IB issues.  If not, try removing the button from the View.  Also check that your File's Owner class is YOUR view controller class.

Comment: Ah. File's Owner might be the source. I'll check, thanks for the tip.

Comment: I've accepted this answer because it's a common gotcha. Mine was a far more stupid result - I've overriden the hittest method for another reason. It was making attempts at touching the taskbar fall through. Silly me.